# Jasmine error: Expected false to be true

Tags: javascript, jasmine

When I test the ability to hide the menu, I get an error saying "Expected false to be true" while toggling off the menu. Displaying the menu works alright but the other one does not. I need to pass all tests. Here is the code. If necessary I will upload the rest of the project. Don't mind the comments please.

```
/* feedreader.js
*
* This is the spec file that Jasmine will read and contains
* all of the tests that will be run against your application.
*/

/* We're placing all of our tests within the $() function,
* since some of these tests may require DOM elements. We want
* to ensure they don't run until the DOM is ready.
*/

$(function() {
/* This is our first test suite - a test suite just contains
* a related set of tests. This suite is all about the RSS
* feeds definitions, the allFeeds variable in our application.
*/
describe('RSS Feeds', function() {
    /* This is our first test - it tests to make sure that the
     * allFeeds variable has been defined and that it is not
     * empty. Experiment with this before you get started on
     * the rest of this project. What happens when you change
     * allFeeds in app.js to be an empty array and refresh the
     * page?
     */
    it('are defined', function() {
        expect(allFeeds).toBeDefined();
        expect(allFeeds.length).not.toBe(0);
    });


    /* TODO: Write a test that loops through each feed
     * in the allFeeds object and ensures it has a URL defined
     * and that the URL is not empty.
     */
     it('url is defined', function() {
        allFeeds.forEach(function(feed) {
        feedLink = feed.url;
        expect(feedLink).toBeDefined();
        expect(feedLink.length).not.toBe(0);
      });
   });


    /* TODO: Write a test that loops through each feed
     * in the allFeeds object and ensures it has a name defined
     * and that the name is not empty.
     */
     it('name is defined', function() {
        allFeeds.forEach(function(feed) {
        feedName = feed.name;
        expect(feedName).toBeDefined();
        expect(feedName.length).not.toBe(0);
      });
   });
});


/* TODO: Write a new test suite named "The menu" */
    /* TODO: Write a test that ensures the menu element is
     * hidden by default. You'll have to analyze the HTML and
     * the CSS to determine how we're performing the
     * hiding/showing of the menu element.
     */

     describe('Menu', function () {
       it('menu hidden', function () {
         expect($('.menu-hidden').is(':visible')).toBe(true);
       });

     /* TODO: Write a test that ensures the menu changes
      * visibility when the menu icon is clicked. This test
      * should have two expectations: does the menu display when
      * clicked and does it hide when clicked again.
      */
        it('toggle on', function () {
          $('.menu-icon-link').trigger('click');
          expect($('.menu-hidden').is(':visible')).toBe(false);
        });

        it('toggle off', function () {
          $('.menu-icon-link').trigger('click');
          expect($('.menu-hidden').is(':visible')).toBe(true);
        });

      });

/* TODO: Write a new test suite named "Initial Entries" */

    /* TODO: Write a test that ensures when the loadFeed
     * function is called and completes its work, there is at least
     * a single .entry element within the .feed container.
     * Remember, loadFeed() is asynchronous so this test will require
     * the use of Jasmine's beforeEach and asynchronous done() function.
     */
     describe('Initial Entries', function() {
       beforeEach(function (done) {
          loadFeed(0, function() {
            done();
          });
       });

       it('entry element', function () {
         expect($('.feed .entry').length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
       });
     });

/* TODO: Write a new test suite named "New Feed Selection" */

    describe('New Feed Selection', function() {
        var testFeed;

    /* TODO: Write a test that ensures when a new feed is loaded
     * by the loadFeed function that the content actually changes.
     * Remember, loadFeed() is asynchronous.
     */

     beforeEach(function(done) {
       loadFeed(0, function() {
         testFeed = $('.feed').html();
         loadFeed(1, done);
       });
     });

     it('if the feeds are different', function() {
       expect($('.feed').html()).not.toEqual(testFeed);
     });
    });
}());
```

Comment: So which line is the one showing the error in the stack trace?

Comment: Here is a picture of it:
https://s8.postimg.cc/vnscjf22d/2018-08-03_23_36_46-_Udaci_Feeds.png

Comment: Please don't post images of errors on external websites, especially websites full of ads that have scantily clad swimsuit models on them.  Post the **textual content** of the error message in the question by clicking the edit button on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your specs for "toggle on" and "toggle off" are exactly the same. Unit tests are run in isolation, so even though your first test toggled the button on, that state does not carry over to the next test. The second test should be more like this:

```
it('toggle off', function () {
  $('.menu-icon-link').trigger('click');
  $('.menu-icon-link').trigger('click');
  expect($('.menu-hidden').is(':visible')).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: I understood what you meant but unfortunately this didn't work too. What else can you suggest?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that perhaps there's some asynchronous action happening that you need to wait for. If so, look up how to use `fakeAsync` and `tick`.